# ENUM data type in h2 and version

Tags: types, enums, h2

I have installed the latest version of H2 (10-06-2017). H2 console window shows version infor as  H2 1.4.192 (2016-05-26) . I am confused over this.Moreover the documentation specifies it supports enum data type. But when running the following sql query

CREATE TABLE  users  (
   user_id  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   password  varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   usertype  enum('admin','doctor','housekeeper') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( user_id )
)

it shows *"Unknown data type: "ENUM"; SQL statement:"*
Please explain. Im using windows 10

Comment: This answer might be helpful: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955100/error-when-setting-up-h2-database/64044332#64044332

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the latest version (1.4.196) does support enums and your CREATE TABLE statement runs fine. The older version (1.4.192) does not support enums and fails as you have described. So the problem is that you are actually running the older version (as per your suspicion in the beginning of the question).

Comment: Could you please provide 1.4.196 download link?

Comment: Absolutely, for Windows: http://www.h2database.com/h2-setup-2017-06-10.exe

Comment: In fact I installed h2 from that exeutable file. Then which causes the error.? Is there any pitfall in the uninstall process of the previous version?